# Play a video online mode and cache it locally for playing in offline?

Tags: caching, video, cordova, local-storage

We have developed an application which is able to download an play the video in offline mode.But as the size of the video is much larger it is not possible for us to make the user wait for long to get video downloaded and play.So we would like to implement progressive download while playing the video but would also like to save the video locally for playing it locally too. Is there any way or any possibility of caching the video in offline mode ? Also can we implement any functionality where in a part of video played or buffered is saved locally and played in offline mode. Also can we make the buffering start or resume from the point where it was stopped when user is online ? Any Suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to download the video using [FileTransfer.download()](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer_download) independently of playing it. Then you could cache the video on the filesystem and play it offline if the user wanted to watch it again.